# Ошибка в боте, помогите решить discord

Tags: python, discord

Писал бота и он работал до того как я добавил эту команду

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel( id channel )
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=id role)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed( title=f'Пользователь ``{member.mention}``, присоединился к нам!', color = discord.Colour.random())
```

Когда я её добавил она не работала но другие команды работали, потом когда я её удалил все команды перестали работать кроме help.
Discord Intents я использовал все.
Вот сама ошибка(command clear):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 288, in next
    return self.messages.get_nowait()
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 189, in get_nowait
    raise QueueEmpty
asyncio.queues.QueueEmpty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 377, in purge
    msg = await iterator.next()
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 290, in next
    raise NoMoreItems()
discord.errors.NoMoreItems

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 34, in clear
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 383, in purge
    await strategy(to_delete)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 301, in delete_messages
    await self._state.http.delete_messages(self.id, message_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Вот бот: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10FzR0HFfvq-5Pr-RYb4jRO_Y_8HG0gtb?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в другом месте. А именно в команде `clear`

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Если у вас не работал ивент `on_member_join`, то скорее всего у вас выключены соответствующие интенты на портале разрабтчика.
[image: screenshot]